# Program crashing when accessing shared_ptr holding QString

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, shared-ptr, qstring

I am testing shared_ptrs and QStrings and I am having a crash which I don't fully understand. Here is the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>

#include <iostream>

class Base {
 public:
  Base(const QString& str1, const QString& str2, const QString& str3) {
   member1_ = std::make_shared<Internal>();
   (*member1_).i1 = str1;
   (*member1_).i2 = str2;
   member2_ = std::make_shared<QString>(str3);
 }
 QString getMember() { return *member2_; }
 QString getInternalMember() { return (*member1_).i1; }
protected:
 Base(const Base&) = default;
 Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
 Base(Base&&) = default;
 Base& operator=(Base&&) = default;

private:
 struct Internal {
  QString i1;
  QString i2;
 };
 std::shared_ptr<Internal> member1_;
 std::shared_ptr<QString> member2_;
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived(const QString& str1, const QString& str2, const QString& str3) : Base(str1, str2, str3) {
   derivedMember_ = 1;
  }
 private:
  int derivedMember_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
 Derived* d1 = new Derived("param1", "param2", "param3");
 std::cout << "d1 created " << d1->getMember().toStdString() << "-" << d1->getInternalMember().toStdString() << std::endl;
 Derived* d2 = d1;
 delete d1;
 std::cout << "d2 created " << d2->getMember().toStdString() << "-" << d2->getInternalMember().toStdString() << std::endl;
 return a.exec();
}
```

Why does this crash? I am using shared_ptrs so after the assignment reference counter should get incremented.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You copy pointers, not objects.

Comment: Since QString uses [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) it's unclear why you would even be in such a situation. There's very little value in using smart pointers here -- let alone pointers at all -- in the first place.

Comment: @MrEricSir I want the QString to be the same for all copied objects. Even if QString uses COW using plain pointers if I modify it it will get copied and objects will have different values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

d2 points to the same object as d1, you delete object and then try call its method (after deleting)

Comment: In this case why, if I change QString by int, doesn't it crash?

Comment: It is undefined behavior.